# How to fix a unknown partition without format?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-formatting, unknown-device

I am not able to resize or mount this unknown partition:

[image: Photo of GParted]

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include some specific details, such as a screenshot from GParted or maybe the output of `lsblk`? Without knowing even a little bit about what you're seeing, it will be almost impossible for anyone to offer you a suggestion that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If GParted does not detect a filesystem on that partition, it is very unlikely that there is anything on it that can be mounted with standard tools.

Mounting means "making a block device available as a subtree of the Linux filesystem tree". For that you generally need support either directly in the `/bin/mount` command, or a filesystem support sub-command typically named `/sbin/mount.xy` for filesystem type *xy*.

There is a limited number of those:

```bsh
sh@balrog:~$ ls -1 /sbin/mount.*
/sbin/mount.cifs
/sbin/mount.exfat
/sbin/mount.exfat-fuse
/sbin/mount.fuse
/sbin/mount.lowntfs-3g
/sbin/mount.ntfs
/sbin/mount.ntfs-3g
```

(from my Xubuntu 18.04 LTS)

And all those filesystem types are known to GParted as well, so if it was one of these, GParted would show it. It would also show if a partition was part of an LVM or encrypted (LUKS) or part of a RAID.

You can still check some more with `lsblk` and `lsblk -f`, but don't get your hopes too high. For all intents and purposes, if GParted doesn't know it, you can't mount it.

That also means that you can't *resize* it because for resizing you'd need tools that are even more specialized. The only thing you can do with that partition right now is to delete it.